# SignalR Hub method is not called

Tags: xamarin, signalr

I have a SignalR hub and two clients (Windows and PCL for Android and iOS). Neither of the clients is able to call some methods on the server. This behaviour is quite odd, since the methods look very similar. Moreover, a colleague of mine is able to call methods I cannot call, and vice versa, does not invoke methods that I invoke with no problems.

Here is an example of a method, which works for me and does not work for my colleague:

```
    public override async Task<bool> RefreshArray(User user, int waitMilis)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        try
        {
            cts.CancelAfter(waitMilis);
            await Proxy.Invoke("RefreshArray", user);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnExceptionOccured(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And a method which does not work for me, but works for my colleague:

```
    public override async Task<bool> RequestInformation(User user, Product product, int waitMilis)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        try
        {
            cts.CancelAfter(waitMilis);
            await Proxy.Invoke("RequestInformation", user, product);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnExceptionOccured(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Yes, me and my colleague have exactly the same code. And no, there are no typos or different arguments. I have tried to get as much data from the client connection as possible, by setting `_connection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;` However, I did not get any information on the invoked methods, just on the replies from the hub. When calling `RefreshArray`, I got exactly the data I requested. When calling `RequestInformation`, the debugger never even hit the breakpoint in the hub method and the _connection.Trace displayed only this: `11:22:45.6169660 - 7bc57897-489b-49a2-8459-3fcdb8fcf974 - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {})`

Has anybody solved a similar issue? Is there a solution?

**UPDATE 1**

I just realized that I have encountered almost the same issue about a year ago ([Possible SignalR bug in Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669362/possible-signalr-bug-in-xamarin-android)). StackOverflow has also pointed me to a question with almost the same issue ([SignalR on Xamarin.iOS - randomly not able to call Hub method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177157/signalr-on-xamarin-ios-randomly-not-able-to-call-hub-method?rq=1)), just related to iOS and Azure. However, I got the same proble even outside Xamarin, on Windows Phone 8.1 and and Windows 10 Universal App. Moreover, I am running the server just locally, so it is not an issue od Azure. Is it really possible, that a 2 years old bug has no solution?

**UPDATE 2**

I have just created a simple console application with SignalR.Client. In the console application every method worked just fine. Amazingly, also the Windows 10 Universal Application started to behave as expected - every hub method was invoked correctly. Windows Phone 8.1 also improved its behaviour (all hub methods invoked). However, every now and then the connection tried to reconnect periodically (for no apparent reason), leading to `Connection started reconnecting before invocation result was received.` error. The Android application still behaved as before.

So I tried to replicate my previous steps and created another console application, but this time with SignalR.Client.Portable library. To my dissapointment, there was no change in the Android application behaviour.

Next week we will start to test our application on iOS, so I really wonder what new oddities will we encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem (at least so it seems). As it turned out, there is some weird stuff going around, when an application receives an answer from SignalR hub. It seems as if the HubProxy was blocked for a certain period of time on Android, while it drops the connection and starts to reconnect periodically on Windows Phone, not waiting for an asnwer from the hub.

The implementation of RefreshArray on the hub was something like this:

```
public async Task RefreshArray(User user)
{
    await Clients.Caller.SendArray(_globalArray);
    await Clients.Caller.SendMoreInformation(_additionalInfo);
}
```

Because the method sent two methods as an answer, the client Proxy got stuck and each platform handled it in its own unexpected way. The reason why some methods were called on my computer and not on colleagues was, simply, because we had different position of breakpoints, which enabled the application to resolve at least some requests and responses.

The ultimate solution was to add some synchronization into the invokation of methods. Now my hub calls only `await Clients.Caller.SendArray(_globalArray);`. This is then handled on the client with a `ArraySent(string[] array)` event, which then subsequently invokes the `SendMoreInformation()` method on the hub.